# Rails query where array attribute contains overlap with other array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, where-clause

I have a model called Listing that represents a listing for an apartment sublet. These sublets can be rented out for different terms (summer, winter, etc). And so, the term for each sublet is stored as a serialized string. (I know this isn't the best way but i'm trying to get this app up) I am creating a filter function for these listings, so users can select what attributes they want in a listing and display the results that match the filter. I am having trouble, however, with the term part. Users can check off which terms they want the listing to be available for, and so this is stored in a serialized array as well. Using rails orm how can I do

```
listing=listing.where("term contains value(s) from input term")
```

basically I want this to return listings where the users preferred terms has atleast one overlap with the listings terms.

i.e. if a listing has terms of summer session 1 and winter and the user selects summer session 1 and spring, that listing should be returned.

Anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
listings = Listing.where('term in (?)', terms)
```

or you can just do:

```
listings = Listing.where(:term => terms)
```

Comment: That returns ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Filters#show SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: Summer 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "listings"  WHERE "listings"."furnished" = 't' AND "listings"."negotiable" = 't' AND "listings"."utilities" = 't' AND "listings"."air_conditioning" = 't' AND "listings"."parking" = 'f' AND "listings"."washer_dryer" = 't' AND "listings"."private_bathroom" = 'f' AND (listings.price <= 700.0) AND (term in 'Summer 1')

Comment: the problem is in the end and tested when i checked off summer 1

Comment: I've updated the answer (had a syntactical error). Give it a try again.

Comment: ok this doesn't produce an error but it doesn't return any results. Isn't the ? going to be the terms that the user enters so shouldn't those terms be in the terms of the listing?

Comment: I'm kinda shooting in the dark here because i don't know what your listings table schema looks like, nor what exactly your user input will be. My example assumes you have a table called `listings` with a column called `term`, and the user inputs `terms` will be like ['winter', 'summer'].

Comment: the listing has a column called term (which can be multiple terms as it is serialized) and the user can filter by term (which can be multiple terms as well)

Comment: both are simply saved as strings but can be serialized

Comment: I don't quite understand your meaning of serialized in this case. You don't serialize string into a database. You serialize an array, hash, or some arbitrary object. Anyway, this probably not the best way to go about storing terms. You'll want to have a many_to_many relationship between `terms` and `listings`. Your life will be a lot easier that way.

Comment: yea what I figured, just trying to see if there was a way around it